# Оптимальный способ создания адаптивного меню

Tags: javascript, ajax, оптимизация-сайтов

Допустим, у нас будет два меню: одно для широких экранов, другое - для узких. Одним CSS-кодом с медиа-запросами не обойтись - у меню разный HTML.

Что будет лучше с точки зрения увеличения быстродействия сайта из двух предложенных ниже опций?

- С помощью JavaScript скрывать одно меню и показывать другое при достижении ключевой ширины окна браузера. В этом случае у нас в одном и том же HTML-файле будет два разных по HTML-структуре, но одинаковых по набору ссылок меню. У одного из них будет `display: none`.
- При достижении ключевой ширины экрана, с помощью JavaScript удалять (именно "удалять", а не скрывать, как в предыдущем случае) одно меню и добавлять через `AJAX` другое. HTML-код будет чище, но при медленном интернете, который всё ещё имеет место быть на мобильных устройствах, меню может подгружаться с сервера дольше, чем хотелось бы.

Answer (score 2):

## Ответ на ваш вопрос:

Быстрее будет так, как вы описали в первом варианте.

## ... но как не прострелить себе и своим пользователям колено?

Как минимум спасти свои ноги можно, отказавшись от JavaScript. И AJAX. Серьезно... я понимаю еще JavaScript, его можно для изобретения велосипеда в особо отчаянных случаях применять, но AJAX-то куда? AJAX вообще следует избегать использовать в рамках дизайна и оформления сайта за редкими исключениями (вроде бесконечной ленты контента как фид во ВКонтакте).

Создайте два меню и поместите их где-нибудь в своей разметке:

```
<nav class="menu-mobile"></nav>
<nav class="menu-desktop"></nav>
```

И добавьте примерно такой CSS:

```
.menu-mobile,
.menu-desktop {
  display: none;
}

/* Для планшетов и меньше */
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .menu-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
}

/* Для "квадратных" десктопных мониторов и выше */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .menu-desktop {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Это **самый** нересурсозатратный и быстрый способ, который можно придумать. Никакого JavaScript и никакого AJAX. И показать другим не стыдно.

Answer (score 0):

### Введение

Самое адекватное для создания `responsive-меню`, это написание одного меню с переходами через `media-запросы` и изменением стилей и так далее. Если у вас разный `HTML`, то в чем проблема управлять им через `javascript`?

ps. Использовать два меню, скрывая одно из них, не является оптимальным решением.

---

### Продолжение...

Если вы хотите использовать `ajax`, то лучше всего подгрузить всю информацию в самом начале, и уже после управлять ей, а не после перехода.

---

### Пример

Хотелось бы увидеть ваш код, для большей детальности ответа.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

```css
body {margin:0;}
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

ul.topnav li {float: left;}

ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #555;}

ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### Дополнение

Если интересно, можете посмотреть различные реализации `responsive-меню` [здесь](http://sitesforprofit.com/incredibly-useful-list-of-responsive-navigation-and-menu-patterns).

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. Нет никаких проблем, чтобы управлять меню с разным HTML через JavaScript. Но если у меня два меню с разным HTML, то какой способ оптимальный?